# postfix-mysql package on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, postfix, centos7

I'm following this [tutorial](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/) on how to install a secure mail server. The guide is for Ubuntu 14.04LTS but I'm doing it with a few modifications for my CentOS 7 system.

I am however stuck on finding/installing a package called `postfix-mysql` that is for using Postfix with a MySQL database.

Doing a `yum search` didn't give anything, nor did googling and there is no info about this package on Postfix's official site. I did however find a HowTo on their site about [Building Postfix for MySQL support](http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html).

Is this package an Ubuntu-only thing or is it under a different name for CentOS? Or is the problem that it just isn't available for CentOS 7 yet? Would I need to compile Postfix to support MySQL or is it even already built-in and doesn't need the `postfix-mysql` package anymore?

It is alot of questions but I'd be grateful if someone who knows more about this to shed some light on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Centos 5.9 postfix includes native mysql support.

You can check dependencies:

```
$ rpm -q --requires postfix | grep mysql
libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) 
libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) 
mysql-libs
```

See also: [[SOLVED] Postfix with MySQL support](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1637) and [CentOS 5.9 Release Notes](http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS5.9)

As alternatives, to checks if postfix installation is compiled with mysql, you can use command [postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.1.html). Command `postconf -m` will list all supported lookup table types.

```
# postconf -m
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
internal
ldap
memcache
mysql
nis
pcre
proxy
regexp
socketmap
static
tcp
texthash
unix
```

As you can see, mysql was listed as supported lookup table.

Comment: Many thanks on the info and also on the `postconf` command. Didn't know about that before.

Comment: You're welcome. The command postconf is a contribution of @masegaloeh. Thanks to him too.

Comment: Ofcourse. A big thanks also to @masegaloeh for the command.